# Ionic : Hardware Back Button Event Listener not executed when modal is open

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, capacitor

In ionic framework when the hardware back button is pressed the following event listener method is executed.

```
document.addEventListener('ionBackButton', (ev) => {
   ev.detail.register(10, () => {
   console.log('Handler was called!');
 });
});
```

But when a modal kept opened then the above method is not executed after pressing the hardware back button. It shows only the following message on the console of android studio

> Notifying listeners for event backButton

Updated :

the following code is for the modal in ionic react

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { IonModal, IonButton, IonContent } from '@ionic/react';

export const ModalExample: React.FC = () => {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

  return (
    <IonContent>
      <IonModal isOpen={showModal} cssClass='my-custom-class'>
        <p>This is modal content</p>
        <IonButton onClick={() => setShowModal(false)}>Close Modal</IonButton>
      </IonModal>
      <IonButton onClick={() => setShowModal(true)}>Show Modal</IonButton>
    </IonContent>
  );
};
```

Comment: To close the modal you have to add above snippet on your modal.ts file

Comment: yes, the modal get closed, but actually, it remains opened in the background, not dismissed.

Comment: share your modal close code.

Comment: I have added the code for closing the modal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution for triggering the hardware back button event listener method, simply by increasing the priority up to 140.

```
document.addEventListener('ionBackButton', (ev) => {
   ev.detail.register(140, () => {
   console.log('Handler was called!');
 });
});
```